# BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, dart, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
> Searched Location:
> D:\flutter_projects\text_recognition\android\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
> D:\flutter_projects\text_recognition\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
> D:\flutter_projects\text_recognition\android\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
> D:\flutter_projects\text_recognition\android\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
> D:\flutter_projects\text_recognition\android\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
> D:\flutter_projects\text_recognition\android\app\google-services.json

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

This is the error I am getting after connecting to firebase and running the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get your `google-services.json` file from firebase console based on [this tutorial](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en) and then you should copy your `google-services.json` to this location:

```
D:\flutter_projects\text_recognition\android\app\
```

Comment: Added google-services.json file still the error persists...

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
* Where
Build file 'D:\flutter_projects\text_recognition\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method Properties() for arguments [] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 6s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Yeah...it worked I had to change few more things...thanks a lot